# Show description when click on image

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my English!
Need help!
I make some program, who show random image after button click.
How i can make description for each image after user click on it ?

Program show random image, and how i can make description for every image in new window when user click on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the `setOnClickListener` method on your button to do what you want.

```
final TextView label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.some_text_label);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        label.setText("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip.

Use a list or hashmap and create a custom class to hold image and image data. (Changes by a commentor)

Use `Math.Random();//Random the id numbers`

Stuff to learn:
Research button events and view flipper events

Here's an example:

My idea for using **weakhashmap** and
for improvements I recommend saving location instead of the bitmap(wastes memory).

```
private WeakHashMap<int, Image> whp = new WeakHashMap<Int, Image>
private int position = 0;

public void onCreate{
    //Do download information or store images from sd card
    //Place it in image class

    loop amount of images{
        image Image = new image(Bitmap_Image, Image_Description);//load image
        whp.add(position, Image);//Note the amount of positions the image is field
        position++;
    }

    //To get bitmap use "whp.get(position).image" <- This code returns a bitmap

    setOnClickListener//Create event to listen on clicked image
    {
        int image_random = new Random().nextInt(position);
        String data = whp.get(image_random).note_item;//Image Description
    }
}



class image{

    Bitmap image;//Actual Image
    String note_item;//Image description

    public void image(Bitmap intake_image, String intake_description){

        this.image = intake_image;
        this.note_item = intake_description;

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, list would probably be more efficient.